# How can I make reusable post types with complex custom field structures?

Tags: custom-post-types, theme-development

It's taking some time for me to get used to the Wordpress platform and terminology so I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction for the info I need.  For lack of being able to explain what I need in "Wordpress language" I made a data structure in TypeScript to illustrate what I want to essentially achieve in Wordpress some type of way.

```
export interface MeasurementProps{
    imperial : number;
    metric   : number;
}

export interface WeightProps{
    lb : number;
    kg : number;
}

export interface DimensionProps{
    width  : MeasurementProps;
    height : MeasurementProps;
    depth  : MeasurementProps;
    weight : WeightProps;
}

export interface RGBProps{
    r : number;
    b : number;
    g : number;
}

export interface ColorProps{
    name        : string;
    rgb_setting : RGBProps;
}

export interface PriceProps{
    usd: number;
    eur: number;
}

export interface ItemProps{
    id           : string;
    title        : string;
    description  : string;
    color        : ColorProps;
    key_features : string[];
    size         : DimensionProps;
    price        : PriceProps;
}
```

If you're not familiar with TypeScript the `ItemProps` interface would shape data into the following object.

```
{
    'id'           : 'some_id',
    'title'        : 'Whatever Title You Want',
    'description'  : 'A bunch of text to describe this thing.',
    'color'        : {
                         'name'        : 'red',
                         'rgb_setting' : { 'r' : 255, 'g' : 0, 'b' : 0 }
                     },
    'key_features' : [
                         'something about 1st feature',
                         'something about 2nd feature',
                         'something about 3rd feature'
                     ],
    'size'         : {
                         'width'  : { 'imperial' : 36.5, 'metric' : 927.1 },
                         'height' : { 'imperial' : 62,   'metric' : 1574.8 },
                         'depth'  : { 'imperial' : 24,   'metric' : 609.6 },
                         'weight' : { 'lb' : 80, 'kg' : 10.886 }
                     },
    'price'        : { 'usd' : 400, 'eur' : 490 }
     
}
```

This example is clearly for some type of product and aside from just this data object I could want to use the `PriceProps` interface in another product type with slightly different options.  I may need the size to be based on length, width and thickness rather than height width and depth but other than that has the same properties meaning I would just create a new interface for the size and re-use the others to shape a new `ItemProps2` interface for that kind of product.

In what manner does wordpress allow us to orchestrate our custom post types so when we create a new post it will have all these fields by default?  So far everything I've come across shows how we would need to add custom fields to each post then modify the markup to display it if it exists.  I haven't found anything at all show how we can achieve objects within objects using custom fields like how `size` is an object that contains the 4 `height`, `width`, `depth` and `weight` objects that each have 2 properties.

I'm ultimately wrapping my head around building an admin plugin that will allow me to batch load products from a json object without having to do them 1 by 1 which I know how to achieve functionally, I'm just having a hard time figuring out how to shape custom data structures and chain them together.  Can someone shed light on how this can be achieved?

Comment: storing structured data inside post meta is an anti-pattern as it's not possible to reliably query structured sub-values. Note that post meta keys are not unique, post meta can be registered, registered meta can have default values, custom fields are purely UI speak ( a custom field is just post meta, the tables, functions, APIs all refer to post meta, it is only the Admin UI that refers to custom fields ), and the meta table is not designed for filtering/grouping posts ( you will see a significant performance decrease if you try to do so that scales with site size, use taxonomies )

Comment: otherwise post meta values are strings, and only strings, there is no such thing as "sub-meta"

Comment: So what would be an effective way to structure and represent this type of data in a wordpress site?

Comment: Does it have to take a nested structure? e.g. why `color: { name: '', 'rgb_setting': '' }` when `color_name` and `color_rgb_setting_r` will do just fine? Why store both imperial and metric when you can store one and calculate the other? ( and _which_ imperial? The USA refused to adopt the imperial system when it was introduced, are you sure you don't mean US Customary units? There _is_ a difference, e.g. 1 imperial ton is 2224lb and 1 US Customary ton is 2000lb )

Comment: And if you can store a meta key multiple times, why do you need special handling for arrays? Note that none of these suggestions are WordPress specific, anybody dealing with noSQL databases will have similar methodologies, post meta are just key value pairs, you don't need to overcomplicate things

Comment: Actually I had just come up with that structure for the sake of providing the example it provides in terms of the shape of the data so I didn't really think that deep into it lol.

I know wordpress works quite differently, which is why I was asking how something like this should be thought about and represented in wordpress and maybe see some examples because I have no clue as to how I would even approach making the typescript example wordpress friendly.

Comment: Create a custom post type and then add custom fields.  Each field can represent one of the datapoints you've listed above.

Comment: Could you please show me an example?  Because you're literally telling me to do the very thing I've set out to learn how to do lol.  I've studied through different docs and tutorials but nothing I come across goes into that amount of depth and complexity.  Before you said we couldn't have nested tiers of data in our post types, now you're saying all the data points could be represented.  Do I have to refactor them to all be on one layer or can I indeed have objects within objects as the code above shows?